# how to do lens correction in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to do barrel correction in opencv.

The formula that I need to implement is:

```
r(s)= (A * r(d)^3 + B * r(d) ^2 + C*r(d) + d) * r(d)
```

I know that openCv has in build capability for lens calibration, but it depends on some parameters which doesn't seems to be similar to above equations.

My questions:

Can I convert my parameters to opencv camera calibration parameter?

Can I use any in build opencv function to unwarp images based on the above equation?

What is the best way to implement the above function in opencv?

Answer (score 0):

This is baasically an [Geometric Image Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html). Yours is a not special case, so you'll need the generic `remap`.

Comment: You are right, but first you need to create the map. How can I create the map easily? Is there any function in opencv to do this without me writing it by myself?

Comment: As I pointed out, yours isn't one covered by OpenCV, so you will have to generate the map yourself. But that shouldn't be exteremely hard given that you already have the function. The map is basically a lookup table for the function, so you just populate the map with the function results.